# When using vue-cli-service build is it possible to get nested .vue files?

Tags: vue-cli-3

I'm building a Vue component library and just came across this page https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component.

I see that you can build components individually by adding a *.vue to glob the components in the specified folder. The problem is I have many components spread across different folders nested in my root folder.

Is there a way to search nested folders for *.vue files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that build targets supports nested globing like this `src/components/**/*.vue`